# Getting a Objects are not valid as a React child error even though I am not trying to render an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the title states, I am making an api request, and then returning a component with the contents of the api request as the prop. However, idk why I keep getting this error.

```
App.js
showPicture = async () =>{

        //console.log(KEY)
        const response = await picOfTheDay.get('',{
            params: {
                date:this.date,
                hd: true,
                api_key: 'KEY'
            }
        });

        //console.log()
        this.setState({picDayFullDescription: response}, ()=>{
            return <PictureOfTheDay date = {this.state.date} picture= {this.state.picDayFullDescription.url} description={this.state.picDayFullDescription.explanation} />
        })
    }


render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {/* <PictureOfTheDay date = {this.state.date} picture= {this.state.picDayFullDescription.url} description={this.state.picDayFullDescription.explanation}/> */}
                {this.showPicture()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

```
PictureOfTheDay.js


class PictureOfTheDay extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div> 
                Hello?
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction

Comment: You need to post a minimal, reproducible example if you want to be helped. Your example is not reproducible. You're missing the class declaration for the component in App.js, among other things.

Comment: I don't have much else of code besides this, the class declaration and a little bit of code about current date. The stuff I left out i believe make no impact on my problem or code.   In my mind, the code above should honestly not be giving me any problems, but for some reason it keeps giving me this error.

Comment: "The stuff I left out i believe make no impact on my problem or code" Doesn't matter if it makes an impact to the problem. If it's needed to reproduce the problem, which it is since it won't compile/run without it, then you need to post it.

Comment: `this.showPicture()` returns a `Promise`. Remove that from the JSX.

Comment: Which means, you'll need to do the async stuff in `componentDidMount` or `componentDidUpdate` and use `this.state` in the `render` function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the function in the render, I would rather put the component on the render and then call the fetch function on some lifecycle hook like `componentDidMount`.

This updates the state, hence re-rendering the component and the `PictureOfTheDay`... If the component does not work with an empty description etc which might be a cause of you wanting to make sure the fields are there, render it conditionally based on the needed information e.g `{this.state.picDayFullDescription && ...}`

```js
// App.js

componentDidMount() {
  this.showPicture();
}

showPicture = async () => {
  const response = await picOfTheDay.get("", {
    params: {
      date: this.date,
      hd: true,
      api_key: "KEY",
    },
  });
  this.setState({ picDayFullDescription: response });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PictureOfTheDay
        date={this.state.date}
        picture={this.state.picDayFullDescription.url}
        description={this.state.picDayFullDescription.explanation}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```